# Add Assistant Actions without publishing in Google Play

Tags: android, app-actions

I have 2 problems with integration of shortcut's capabilities (but the shortcuts themselves work properly) in Android:

1. Assistant doesn't see my debug application on phrase "Open myappname"
2. Assistant doesn't see any shortcut capability which I added to the dynamic shortcuts.

If I clearly understand it will be able after publication at the Google Play, but my application is not designed for this store. How can I force Google Assistant to understand my queries?

Comment: Any number of things could be going on here.  Without seeing your implementation details and understanding exactly what doesn't work the way you expect, there's not much we can do to help.  I suggest taking your two questions and splitting them up into two different posts (this is required for Stack Overflow, else your question might get closed as "needs focus").  In each post explain clearly how to reproduce the behavior that isn't meeting your expectation, showing your implementation details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For app actions, your application needs to be uploaded to the Google Play Store. That being said, it doesn't need to be published to everyone. At the very least you can create an [internal or closed test release](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/get-started#test-release).